# How to send list of files as part of a Retrofit 2 body alongside other regular string fields in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

as the question says, I need to send a list of files (images in my case) in a http POST request, but there are other fields alongside it (regular strings). The post looks something like this (as form data):

```
type: customerQuery
user: userId
message: The customer query etc.
contact_number: 01234564789
contact_email: email@address.com
files[]: list of files, as binary
```

I have file uploads working fine when I am only sending the files, as follows:

```
  @Multipart
  @POST("/exampleendpoint/{id}")
  suspend fun uploadDocument(
      @Path("id") id: String,
      @Part document: MultipartBody.Part
  ): Response<Unit>
```

How do I construct the retrofit interface/service to have a list of Files, and also other fields?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try Retrofit example? https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server

Comment: I am literally reading this article, and the "Upload a Dynamic Amount of Files" section as we speak. Doesn't make crystal clear about adding lots of other fields, I'm assuming I just add lots of @Part fields with RequestBody for each one?

Comment: There is `@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files`. Other fields should be as `@Part` with required data

Comment: Yeah it's learning that I literally need a `@Part` and `RequestBody` for each other form field that was initially stumping me. Thanks though I think I'm pretty much there now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thought I'd add my own answer for anybody using Kotlin, also this is the correct answer if **you need to have your list of files/images named, like the rest of the form data**. The accepted answer works if you don't need this, but in my case it didn't work as they had to be under `files[]`.

Retrofit Service (just a simple `@Body body: RequestBody` field, and remove @Multipart)

```
@POST("exampleendpoint/{id}")
fun uploadDocuments(@Path("id") id: String, @Body body: RequestBody): Response<Unit>;
```

Then you need to construct a complete RequestBody including all that you need, an example as below:

```
val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).apply {
  addFormDataPart("type", "booking")
  addFormDataPart("user", "username")
  addFormDataPart("message", "message text goes here")
  addFormDataPart("contact_number", "0123456789")
  addFormDataPart("contact_email", "email@address.com")
  // my files are List<ByteArray>, okhttp has a few utility methods like .toRequestBody for various types like below
  files.forEachIndexed { index, bytes ->
     addFormDataPart("files[]", "$index.jpg", bytes.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), 0, bytes.size))
  }
}.build()
service.uploadDocuments("uploadId", requestBody)
```

Answer (score 3):

do it

```
@Multipart
@POST("exampleendpoint/{id}")
Call<Unit> uploadDocument(@Path("id") String id,
                          @Part("type") RequestBody type,
                          @Part("user") RequestBody user,
                          @Part("message") RequestBody message,
                          @Part("contact_number") RequestBody contact_number,
                          @Part("contact_email") RequestBody contact_email,
                          @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> file);
```

and add list of files like this

```
ArrayList<File> tempFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> images = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < tempFilesList.size(); i++) {
    images.add(prepareImageFilePart("files" + (i + 1), tempFilesList.get(i).getImage()));
}

@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareImageFilePart(String partName, File file) {
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("image/jpg"),
                    file
            );
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

you can create `RequestBody` of other fields like this

```
RequestBody type = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "your data...");
```

Comment: Top part of question looks good, and is what I've just come to myself from reading the futurestud.io link in comment of answer... - is `prepareImageFilePart()` your own utility method? Would love to see this code if so

Comment: excellent, yeah this looks good. Seems to me you've sourced the code from the same futurestud.io article, but it's good. I may do a Kotlin answer too below as there's some useful extension functions for converting strings easily to RequestBody e.g. `theString.toRequestBody()`